# How to find outlier bins in multinomial distribution?

Tags: outliers, multinomial-distribution

Assume we are throwing $n$ balls randomly into $m$ bins, according to the probabilities $p_i$ associated with each bin. The multinomial distribution describes this situation, and we can calculate the probability of measuring $x_i$ balls in bin $i$.

Now assume, we are given a different set of counts $x_i$ and we know $n$ and $p_i$. I would like to find bins that are high outliers, or in other words that the number of balls in each such bin is significantly higher than expected from the multinomial distribution.

One possible strategy would be to calculate a binomial p-value for the counts in each bin, and then do some kind of multiple testing correction. Is this a good approach? Are there other alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean by "significantly higher than expected from the multinomial distribution"? Are you just wondering about the goodness of fit of a dataset to a given dataset?

Comment: @gung if for example the probabilities are (0.1,0.45,0.45), and we observe the counts (1000,5,5), bin 1 has much more balls than expected since we expect it to have ~10% of the balls. How can we find this outlier? Now imagine a case where we have 100 bins with uniform probabilities, and we observe 5 bins with counts that are much higher than the rest. How can we identify these outlier bins?

Comment: This question seems clear enough & sufficiently well constrained to be answerable to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 2):

What you are getting at is a goodness of fit test of an empirical distribution (i.e., your data) to a theoretical / pre-specified distribution.  Since this instance is categorical, you can use the chi-squared test for goodness of fit.  Here is your example, analyzed with R:

```r
chisq.test(c(1000,5,5), p=c(0.1,0.45,0.45))

#   Chi-squared test for given probabilities
# 
# data:  c(1000, 5, 5)
# X-squared = 8891.1, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

From this, we might infer that the empirical distribution does not look like the theoretical one.

You subsequently want to know *which* cell causes this result.  In some sense, the answer is all of them.  One way to explore this is to examine the Pearson residuals<sup>1</sup> of the specified model:

```r
chisq.test(c(1000,5,5), p=c(0.1,0.45,0.45))$residuals
# [1]  89.45384 -21.08447 -21.08447
```

The largest deviation is occurs in the first category.

---

1. The Pearson residuals are: $(O-E)/\sqrt{E}$.

Comment: Thanks. The issue with the residuals is that it is not clear what value can be considered an outlier. What do you expect the residuals to be if you actually sample from these probabilities? how likely is it to get a certain residual? This is why I was thinking of using a statistical test to find the outliers, since you can say how likely it is to get this specific outlier count.

Comment: That isn't an appropriate use for statistical tests, @user149114. If you want the likelihood, you can use the binomial likelihood to get the likelihood of the observed count in a given cell. If you wanted a test, you could use a binomial test for the given cell, but you should correct for multiple comparisons, since you looked at the data to decide this is the cell you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any way to calculate a p value besides your idea. However, I can see another way of getting a valid statistical test.

Let's say, there's two requirements:

1. We want to choose some subset of the bins.
2. We want to control the family-wise error rate (FWER). That is, if the null hypothesis is true, the probability that we will choose *any* bin is $\alpha$ or less. ($\alpha$ is probably .05).

And we can divide our work into two parts.

1. Given a rule for choosing bins, calculate the FWER.
2. Find a good rule with FWER $\le \alpha$.

### Calculating FWER

Suppose your rule sets cutoffs for each bin. So, if $N_1$ (the first bin) is larger than $c_1$, you select it; if $N_2$ is larger than $c_2$, you select it; etc. The cutoffs don't need to be the same as each other, and should probably be pretty small for small probabilities.

Note that I said "larger than": so if the cutoff is 5, you'll select the bin if it's 6 or more. This is just because it makes the math below convenient.

The family-wise error rate, then, is:

$$P(N_1 > c_1 \lor N_2 > c_2 \lor \cdots \lor N_k > c_k)$$

where $k$ is the number of bins, and $\lor$ is "or". This is the probability of at least one bin being selected, which under the null hypothesis is a type I error. Re-writing this probability:

$$1 - P(N_1 \le c_1 \land N_2 \le c_2 \land \cdots \land N_k \le c_k)$$

That is, one minus the probability that they're all *below* the threshold of being selected. Now we have something we can easily calculate. For example, let's say we rolled a die 60 times, and we want to find sides which are favored, and our cutoff is 20 (we're requiring 21 to call it as favored). Using [my R package pmultinom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmultinom/index.html),

```
null.dist <- c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)
cutoffs <- c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20)
1 - pmultinom(upper=cutoffs, size=60, probs=null.dist, method="exact")
# [1] 0.002713616
```

So, we find that this rule was actually stricter than it had to be. The FWER is an order of magnitude lower than .05.

### Choosing cutoffs

So, you already thought of a way of choosing cutoffs. Your cutoff for a bin is based on a p-value from the binomial distribution. And you pointed out that this gives you a multiple-testing problem. So what I'm going to do is solve the multiple testing problem. We're going to choose a cutoff for your binomial tests that controls the FWER. Basically, what's the loosest p-value cutoff that gives us an FWER of $\alpha$?

To put it mathematically, all our cut-offs are now functions of $p$:

$$c_i(p) = \min_c P(N_i > c) \le p$$

That is, it's the lowest cutoff $c$ such that $c+1$ gives a binomial p-value of $p$ or less.

Let's take a more interesting example, so our cutoffs are different from each other. This is from [a paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-009-3049-0_10) where the author had 20,000 rolls displaying a distinct bias, and was trying to find a model that fit them. First tried was an assumption that the 6 side is a little lighter than the 1 side, and in general that carving out the pips makes sides a little lighter. The resulting theoretical distribution was:

```
theoretical.dist <- c(.15294, .15818, .16361, .16922, .17502, .18103)
```

That's the probability for 1, 2, 3, etc. So our question is: which sides are observed more frequently than this distribution can explain? We want to calculate a vector of cutoffs $c_1, \cdots, c_6$.

So, calculating the FWER for each binomial p-value cutoff:

```
# Cutoff function
cutoff <- Vectorize(function(prob, target.pval, size)
{
  pvals <- 1 - pbinom(0:size, size, prob)
  min((0:size)[pvals <= target.pval])
})
# p values we want to try (just 100 values between 0 and .05)
xvals <- seq.int(0, .05, length.out=100)
# FWER for each of these values
yvals <- unlist(mclapply(xvals,
  function(p) 1 - pmultinom(upper=cutoff(theoretical.dist, p, 2e4), size=2e4,
                            probs=theoretical.dist, method="exact"),
  mc.cores=4))
plot(xvals, yvals, type='l',
     main="Controlling family-wise error rate", xlab="binomial p-value", ylab="FWER")
```

[image: controlling familywise error rate]

From the plot it looks like a p-value of .01 for our tests on each cell will give us an FWER of .05. More precisely:

```
max(xvals[yvals <= .05])
# [1] 0.008080808
```

So .008 is the highest p value we can get away with in our bin-specific tests, and still keep FWER below .05.

The advantage is that this is probably more powerful than using a generic method for controlling FWER, like the Bonferroni or Holm adjustments. The disadvantage is that we just get yes-or-no answers, rather than adjusted p values.

Anyway, let's actually use this. I want to see which sides passed these cutoffs. So the vector of cutoffs is:

```
cutoff(theoretical.dist, 0.008080808, 2e4)
# [1] 3182 3288 3399 3512 3630 3752
```

And the actual observations were:

```
      3246 3449 2897 2841 3635 3932
```

So, we exceeded the cutoffs for sides 1, 2, 5 (just barely), and 6. We can say that we rejected those four null hypotheses, with FWER controlled at .05 (if the theoretical distribution were true, 95% of the time, we would come up with nothing). This is also what the author concluded, in the paper I'm pulling this from. He explained this by saying the die is a little bit long, so the 1, 2, 5 and 6 faces are a little larger.

But statistically, I think what we did here is actually a little better than the author's analysis. The author used a chi-squared test, which just rejected the fit of the distribution as a whole, and then picked out these four sides without additional statistical tests. We actually did side-specific tests.

Anyway, that's how I'd solve your problem, if generic p-value adjustments weren't cutting it. I should add that my pmultinom package is on the slow side for an application like this. You saw that I had to parallelize the calculation, and it still took about a minute. There's [another pmultinom package](https://github.com/fennerm/pmultinom) which also has the functionality used here. I haven't tried it, but it should be faster because it uses an approximate calculation. The downside is that it's not as accurate: the examples in the Github readme show error in the second digit. (for example, compare the first example given to dbinom(2, size=4, prob=1/2), which should come out the same.)

Another idea to address the speed issue--that FWER vs binomial p value plot basically looks like a line. Maybe you can do a linear approximation, and get a slope by taking a derivative somehow.